# How to get a list size?

Tags: java, android, list

In my application I want get some list from server and I should first check it.
If **notified** is **false**, then **add** this into my **List**.
For this I write **foreach** for read all of **list** from server.

**My Code is :**

```
private void getNotificationCountData() {
    ExploreSendData sendData = new ExploreSendData();
    sendData.setPageIndex(1);
    sendData.setPageSize(10);
    sendData.setShowFollows(true);
    sendData.setShowMovies(false);
    sendData.setShowNews(false);
    sendData.setShowReplies(true);
    sendData.setShowSeries(false);
    sendData.setShowSuggestions(true);

    InterfaceApi api = ApiClient.getClient().create(InterfaceApi.class);
    Call<ExploreResponse> call = api.getExplore(token, sendData);

    call.enqueue(new Callback<ExploreResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ExploreResponse> call, Response<ExploreResponse> response) {
            if (response.body().getData() != null && response.body().getStatusCode() != 401
                    && response.body().getStatusCode() != 402) {
                if (response.body().getData().size() > 0) {
                            seen.clear();
                    for (Datum datum : response.body().getData()) {
                        //Set not seen
                        if (!datum.getNotified()) {

                            seen.add(datum);
                            Log.e("Notification", "MAIN notified : " + datum.getNotified());
                        }

                        if (!datum.getNotified()) {
                            // Badges
                            AHNotification notification = new AHNotification.Builder()
                                    .setText(seen.size() + "")
                                    .setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.colorAccent))
                                    .setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.cardview_light_background))
                                    .build();
                            mainBottomNav.setNotification(notification, 3);
                        }
                    }
                    Log.e("Notification", "Seen Size : " + seen.size());
                }
            } else {
                prefrencesHandler.remove(SharedPrefrencesKeys.TOKEN.name());
                startActivity(new Intent(context, LoginActivity.class));
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<ExploreResponse> call, Throwable t) {
        }
    });
}
```

**My LogCat message :**

```
12-30 11:19:23.866 1507-1507/com.test.app E/Notification: MAIN notified : false
12-30 11:19:23.868 1507-1507/com.test.app E/Notification: MAIN notified : false
12-30 11:19:23.868 1507-1507/com.test.app E/Notification: MAIN notified : false
12-30 11:19:23.869 1507-1507/com.test.app E/Notification: MAIN notified : false
12-30 11:19:23.869 1507-1507/com.test.app E/Notification: MAIN notified : false
12-30 11:19:23.869 1507-1507/com.test.app E/Notification: Seen Size : 1
```

In `logCat` show me **5 false** message, why in size show me **1**?!!! 
**In size message should show me 5 . not 1**

How can I it? please help me

Comment: guess what clear does ...

Comment: check size of response.body().getData().size()

Comment: @kamalverma, if show size of `response.body().getData().size()` show me 10 . I want just show notifies == false size

Comment: @Kdo try https://stackoverflow.com/a/48032146/6834114 this...

Comment: add this code seen.clear(); before the for-each loop. because every time for-each execute it will clear the List and at last only one result is add.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add `clear()` before `foreach` like below

```
if (response.body().getData().size() > 0) {
                    seen.clear();// change here
                    for (Datum datum : response.body().getData()) {
                        //Set not seen
                        if (!datum.getNotified()) {

                            seen.add(datum);
                            Log.e("Notification", "MAIN notified : " + datum.getNotified());
                    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Each time `getNotified` is `false`, you clear the `seen` list, which removes all the elements from it. Just remove that line and you should be OK:

```
if (!datum.getNotified()) {
    // seen.clear(); // This line should be removed
    seen.add(datum);
    Log.e("Notification", "MAIN notified : " + datum.getNotified());
}
```

Comment: yes my dear. if I remove `seen.clear` show me **5** ! but I should run this code every 60sec ! if I run this code ever 60sec, then ever up 5 this list. first show 5, second show 10 and ...    . sorry for my bad English . please help me my friend

Comment: can you help me my friend?

Answer (score 1):

When You add `seen.add(datum)` before you clear  `seen.clear()`

Remove `seen.clear()`

```
 if (!datum.getNotified()) {
                        seen.clear();
                        seen.add(datum);
                        Log.e("Notification", "MAIN notified : " + datum.getNotified());
                    }
```

Comment: yes my dear. if I remove `seen.clear` show me **5** ! but I should run this code every 60sec ! if I run this code ever 60sec, then ever up 5 this list. first show 5, second show 10 and ...    . sorry for my bad English . please help me my friend

Comment: can you help me my friend?